# If $Ax = b$ has many solutions, then $Ax = 0$ has many solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix and let $x, b$ be $n \times 1$ vectors. Is it true that, if the equation $Ax = b$ has more than one solution, then $Ax = 0$ has more than one solution as well?

I was thinking of an argument along the lines of: if $Ax=b$ has many solutions, then the reduced row echelon form of $A$ has at least one non-pivot entry (associated to a free variable of the system). So $Ax = 0$ will also be equivalent to a system with a free variable, therefore having more than one solution.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: That is correct. Not only that, but in fact if the space of solutions of $Ax=0$ has dimension $k$, the space of solutions of $Ax=b$ (assuming that it has inf. many solutions) has the same dimension, and it is a shifted version of the previous.

Comment: I think it's easier to attack this algebraically: if $Ax_1=Ax_2=b$, think about applying distributivity to $Ax_1-Ax_2$ ...

Comment: The solutions to $Ax=b$ have the form $s+x_0$, where $s$ is a particular solution to $Ax=b$, and $x_0$ is a solution to $Ax=0$. In particular, $Ax=b$ has either no solutions at all, or exactly as many solutions as $Ax=0$ has.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x_h$ represents all solutions to the equation $Ax=0$, namely, $Ax_h=0$.

and $x_p$ is a particular solution to the equation $Ax=b$, namely, $Ax_p=b$,

then $x_h+x_p$ is also a solution to this equation, because

$$A(x_h+x_p)=Ax_h+Ax_p=0+b=b$$

Since the dimension of the null space is $\ge1$, which means there are infintely many solutions for $x_h$, hence infinitely many solutions for $x_h+x_p$

Comment: $\alpha x_h+x_p$ is an infinite family of solutions of $Ax=b$.

Comment: Yes, what I mean $x_h$ is the family of solutions to $Ax=0$, you take $x_h$ as one particular choice.